# HTML not linking to CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to the forms, so excuse me.
For some odd reason, it may just be because it's 1 AM I just can't link CSS properly!They are in the same folder, no sub-folders or anything (on mac btw) and it's just not linking up. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="nav">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you can check your CSS file through view source page in browser.

Comment: I see in in the inspect element, however the color I have set for container isn't showing.

Comment: that's the problem your css in not linked still..that's why i said first see css file thorugh view page source and search your css there and click on it.

Comment: where did you place your css file ?

Comment: Same folder as the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

-Check to see if style.css is available in your browser.
 -Check your spelling. 
-Try copying over the contents of the .css file into your current file.
-Open up developer mode (f12) and see if the div recognizes the class container, and see if there is an error there.

Please post links to the project so we can help.
**Tell me if none of these work below in the comments.**

Comment: Tried that. The browser sees the CSS, however it is not being styled in Safari.

Comment: Post a link to your page, I will debug it.

Comment: I think I went waaayyyy out of order. I applied a color to the body in the css file and it worked, however nothing else seems to be working.

Comment: Like I said, you need to post a link or give the full contents of both files.

Answer (score 0):

The correct location for the style.css file should be in the exact directory and level as your .html file:

|
|-- index.html
|-- style.css

See if the .css file is loaded by opening your web client and using inspector tools. See if the .css file appears in Style Editor.

The color for the container class should be set this way:

```
.container {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

where red and white are examples.